# Excel data - cleaning data with multiple values for numerous instances

Tags: excel, graph, data-cleaning

I have a data set which is related to force applied vs distance traveled.

When the data was created the measurement software has provided multiple values for distance traveled as the force increases, then in some cases the data has no values for distance at the force values.

I have several data sets which look like this.

The data looks like this

[image: Raw data]

I want to 'clean the data so I can create a graph with all 3 samples in columns the same height so it is easy to edit and make scatter graphs from.

I tried to clean the data by using VLOOKUP to create a column of force values at each 0.5N, but when I do this I end up with a large table that has lots of missing data points, when I make the graph from this there are lots of blank areas which don't seem to plot correctly.

The VLOOKUP data looks like this

[image: VLOOKUP combined data]

The graph looks like this

[image: VLOOKUP graph]

Is there a better way to do this which will give me a better looking data set which is better for creating a graph from?

I have about 30 sets of data, so any info that you have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Chris, just want to hint You https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why make the columns equal length.

If you plot the three samples with the data as given, an XY graph should look OK:

[image]

If there's some other reason to make the columns equal length, I'd "fill in the blanks" using the `FORECAST` or `GROWTH` functions, or use a trendline.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, I think i was overthinking the process. I will have a look at the forecast and growth functions and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFERROR` to insert something in place of the #N/As.  For example, you could use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,D:D,1,FALSE),0)` to add a zero in place of the #N/As